# How to display data from the couchbase lite database in other activity or a fragment

Tags: android, couchbase-lite

I would like to use Couchbase lite as my database.

The [examples provided by couchbase](http://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/mobile/1.2/develop/training/build-first-android-app/starter-code-android/index.html) suggest to create the Manager and the database directly in the main activity in the onCreate method, which I did.

I also added a viewpager in my app with two pagefragments.

What do I actually now have to do, to display data saved in Couchbase in one of my Fragments?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! You might want to keep reading [Performing CRUD operations](http://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/mobile/1.2/develop/training/build-first-android-app/do-crud/index.html). StackOverflow isn't a tutorial service. You may [edit] your question if you have something implemented that isn't working.

Comment: There are also a list of [sample](http://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/mobile/1.2/develop/samples/samples/index.html) applications that you can just read the code for and copy from.

Comment: What exactly do you want to do? Couchbase lite is an embedded database for an application. if you want to show all documents save in the database, you should use the built-in view of "alldocuments"